# Unexpected behavior when using the same component twice in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two objects `incs` and `exps` each has the properties: `desc`, `amount` and `id`. I would like to display the details of each object in a container as a list, and the two containers are side-by-side. I did it like this

```
const Details = props => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.detailsItem}>
        <ul>
          {props.balance.incs.map(inc => (
            <DetailsItem item={inc} key={inc.id}/>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div className={styles.detailsItem}>
        <ul>
          {props.balance.exps.map(exp => (
            <DetailsItem item={exp} key={exp.id}/>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

where `DetailsItem.js` is given by

```
const DetailsItem = ({item}) => {
  return (
    <li className={styles.listItem}>
      <div>{item.desc}</div>
      <div>{item.amount}</div>
    </li>
  )
}
```

The `.scss` file is

```
.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  .detailsItem {
    width: 49%;
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    h2{
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    .listItem {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 2rem;
      padding: 0.5rem 0;
    }
    li:nth-child(even) {
      background: rgb(219, 217, 217);
    }
  }
}
```

The objects `incs` and `exps` are filled via a form. But when I add an `incs` entry, the `exps` container grows by the same amount `incs` container grows, although if the number of entries in `exps` is 0 or less than the number of entries in `incs`, and vice versa. See attached image. This is not a desired result. Why is this happening, and how to make each container grows according to the size of their object only?

[image]

Comment: I think the issue is due to your style `detailsItem`. Can you post your CSS and how you are adding entries in `incs`?

Comment: The css file has been included in my question

Comment: Hi, check my solution and let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try handling the case where the exps is empty. Set css to display:none etc. It is difficult to help without the css code.
You can also try enclosing the exps block inside an if codition to not show exps if the length is 0.

Comment: The css file has been included in my question

Comment: BTW, it's not only when `exps` is empty. For example if the number of entries in `incs` is 5 and the number of entries in `exps` is 3, then both containers grow to accommodate 5 entries, i.e., the `exps` container will have two empty rows. I don't want it to grow unless it has more entries.

Answer (score 0):

As you have used `flexbox` it is expected behaviour.

You can have 2 options here.

1) **With flexbox** - You need to add condition so that when `incs` / `exps` array are empty the respective `div` should get hide **(but when both array's length is not equal it will still show the same height box due to flexbox)**.

```
<div className={styles.container}>
  { props.balance.incs.length > 0 &&   //add condition
    <div className={styles.detailsItem}>
      <ul>
        {props.balance.incs.map(inc => (
          <DetailsItem item={inc} key={inc.id}/>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  }
  { props.balance.exps.length > 0 && //add condition
    <div className={styles.detailsItem}>
      <ul>
        {props.balance.exps.map(exp => (
          <DetailsItem item={exp} key={exp.id}/>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  }
</div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9jtv53)

---

2) **Without flexbox** - You can try out `float: left` & `float: right` and remove flexbox completely. In this way you can achieve what you want. It will display the box as per the size of the array.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zlqwxw)

Comment: I see. I prefer to use Flexbox, though, because it's easier with no clearfix and that stuff. What I ended up doing is just to remover the background color of the containers. This creates the illusion that the containers grow according to the corresponding object they are displaying, even though technically they will both have the same size all the time.